# Answer to simple algebraic formula manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to show that

$2y+(x + 1) = 3 \cdot 2^{x+1}− (x + 1) − 2$

is equal to

$y=3⋅2^x−x−2$

I can get this far:

$2y+(x+1)=3⋅2^{x+1}−(x+1)−2$
$2y+(x+1)=3⋅2^{x+1}−x−1−2$
$2y+(x+1)=3⋅2^{x+1}−x−3$
$2y+x+1=3⋅2^{x+1}−x−3$
$2y=3⋅2^{x+1}−x−3−1−x$
$2y=3⋅2^{x+1}−2x−4$

Now I should divide by 2, but the 3 on the right side throws me off. Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide $3 \cdot 2^{x+1}$ by $2$ you obtain $3 \cdot 2^x$, since $2^{x+1}=2 \cdot 2^{x}$

Comment: if I divided $3 \cdot 2^{x+1}$ by $2$, wouldn't that be $\frac{3 \cdot 2^{x+1}}{2}$? I mean, let's say $x = 3$. Then $3 \cdot 2^3$ would be $2^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 +2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$. Dividing this by $2$ would be $\frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 +2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}{2}$.

Comment: Yes but $\frac{3 \cdot 2^{x+1}}{2}= \frac{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^{x}}{2}= 3 \cdot 2^x$. The second equation holds since $2^{x+1} = 2 \cdot 2^{x}$.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right.

Comment: You're welcome :).

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed one $x$ to be an exponent. Go ahead and divide by $2$ to get:
$$
y= 3\cdot \frac{2^{x+1}}2+x-2=3\cdot {2^{x}}+x-2
$$